# About philosophy behind mathematics of Lagrange mechanics and Newtonian mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

I wanted to ask how does Euler-Lagrange mechanics describe the Newtonian mechanics?
By which i mean , since this results are mathematical and not something we found using experiment,afaik , it should be the case , i think , that at some fundamental level F=ma is equivalent to some equation in Lagrange equations so that both can describe the same thing , otherwise i think it would be too coincidental. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can derive one from the other. This and the corresponding thing with Hamiltonian mechanics is a standard thing in classical mechanics textbooks.

Comment: You can see Matthew Benacquista & Joseph David Romano, [Classical mechanics (Springer, 2018)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Classical_Mechanics/PIIltAEACAAJ) as well as Emmanuele DiBenedetto, [Classical Mechanics:  Theory and Mathematical Modeling (Birkhauser, 2011)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Classical_Mechanics/n7ECDQEACAAJ)

Comment: If the question is whether the classical mechanics is based on observations. Yes, this is the case. In contrary to many modern physical theories.

Comment: @Peter What do you mean? Most modern physical theories are very much based on observations. Sure, there is string theory and supersymmetry. But those are just hopeful offshoots of extremely successful, thoroughly established, observation-based physical theories.

Answer (score 1):

It works because of [the least action principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%27s_principle), which is the most fundamental principle of modern physics. But I doubt if there is an explanation of why it works in the real world apart from it works because it works ([Wigner was discussing this a lot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unreasonable_Effectiveness_of_Mathematics_in_the_Natural_Sciences)).

In short, it means that every system has an action which it tries to minimize. The mathematical minimization of this variational problem for classical mechanical system, results in Euler-Lagrange equations. If you select cartesian coordinates to describe your system, Euler-Lagrange equations give Newtonian equations. Thus, Newtonian mechanics is just a specific case of Euler-Lagrange mechanics and its results/predictions can be confirmed in experiments.

Comment: But is the converse possible? That is can we derive Euler Lagrange from Newton’s equations? Cas if thats the case i am curious how one could have seen it , especially since euler Lagrange is kinda nonvectorish where F=ma uses vectors “a lot”

Comment: Euler-Lagrange equations are no less “vectorish” than Newton ones. They just don't constraint their vectors to lie in $\mathbb R^3$. I am not sure about the word “derive”, but you can transform a full set of the Newtonian equations to get any other form of Euler-Lagrange since they describe the same system.

Comment: Just to clarify. Newton formalism works with coordinates $\mathbf r\in\mathbb R^n$, whereas Euler-Lagrange equations can work on any nice manifold parameterized by $\mathbf q$. And although $\mathbf q$ do not belong to a vector space in general, $\dot{\mathbf q}$ belongs to a tangent vector space, so the equations are in vector form.

Comment: Ah , it seems those answers exceed my , at the least current, maths abilities. But thanks , knowing that EL is no less vectorish is intriguing .